# editing xml data in php

Tags: php, xml

I want this code to replace in the "platform" tag with something like "newData"

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('myhappyfarmsave.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$elements = $xpath->query('/myhappyfarmsave/platform');

$domElement = $elements->item(0);
var_dump($domElement->textContent);
$domElement->textContent = "newData";

$xml->save('myhappyfarmsavenew.xml');
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. thanks for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myhappyfarmsave version="3">
    <platform>Bazaar</platform>
    <timestamp>1356876534</timestamp>
    <lastlogtime>1356823542</lastlogtime>
</myhappyfarmsave>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `$node->textContent` is a `readonly` value, so you cannot modify it.

Try playing with `$node->nodeValue` instead:

```
$domElement = $elements->item(0);
$domElement->nodeValue = "newData";

$xml->save('myhappyfarmsavenew.xml');
```

Comment: Be careful with that, nodeValue does not escape &.